# how to add a button to a cell as each row added to datagrid view in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to populate a datagridview using a button click event.Each time button is clicked a row will be added to the datagridview with data in some text boxes(cbCondition,cbVersion,etc).I need to add a "Remove" button to the last cell of each row.My current code add a column of buttons in each click.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string[] conditions={cbCategory.Text,cbName.Text,cbCondition.Text,cbVersion.Text};
        dgConditions.Rows.Add(conditions);
        addRowButton(dgConditions);
 
}

private void addRowButton(DataGridView dg)
{
        DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dgConditions.Columns.Add(btn);
        btn.Name = "Remove";
        btn.Text = "Remove";
        btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DataGridView is not populated with data bindings, why not creating the DataGridViewButtonColumn at design time instead of runtime?

Otherwise, you can just check if the column already exist with `dgConditions.Columns.Contains("Remove")`